# References at the end of each chapter

Tags: bibliographies

Is there a package or template I can use where I can put the references at the end of each chapter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code, this question is difficult to answer because any solution must work with what you already have.

However, this problem is addressed in UK-TUG's [frequently asked questions](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-chapbib.html):

> A separate bibliography for each ‘chapter’ of a document can be provided with the package `chapterbib` (which comes with a bunch of other good bibliographic things). The package allows you a different bibliography for each `\include`d file (i.e., despite the package’s name, the availability of bibliographies is related to the component source files of the document rather than to the chapters that logically structure the document).
>
> The package `bibunits` ties bibliographies to logical units within the document: the package will deal with chapters and sections (as defined by LaTeX itself) and also defines a `bibunit` environment so that users can select their own structuring.
>
> The `biblatex` package, with `biber`, provides a similar facility; enclose the text for which you want a local bibliography in a `refsection` environment, and place a `\printbibliography` command as the last thing in that environment:
>
> ```
> \begin{refsection}
> \chapter{First chapter}
> \section{Foo}
> Some text \cite{this}
> with citations \cite{that}.
> \printbibliography
> \end{refsection}
> ```
>
> Then process with LaTeX (of whatever flavour) and use `biber` to process the bibliography output. Note that `\printbibliography` can take an optional argument `heading=bib title` to provide the bibliography with a (sub)section title.

For more information you may wish to refer to the documentation for [`biber`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber), [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), [`bibunits`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibunits) and [`chapterbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib).

Comment: I see. Sorry for the inconvenience. I'll check this. Thank you.

Comment: @Fib1123 No inconvenience--it's simply a matter of knowing where to look for answers. :) By the way, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: First link is dead!